# Is it possible to save 4 variables that hold sliced arrays into a single variable?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

(Noob) I have a program that takes an array and slices certain elements depending on their individual functionalities and then arCalc operates on them. Returning all those values from arSlice doesnt seem feasible because then the function call in main() expects 5 arguments and I would like to complete this without declaring globals. I was wondering if it is possible to save the variables in arSlice into a single variable so that way I can return only intcodes and result.

Also to be clear: returning a value from a function does not make it so other functions have access to that returned value? I am returning intcodes in getFile but am somehow able to access it in arSlice?

```py
    def getFile(open_file):

    with open(open_file, 'r') as f:
        intcodes = f.readline().split(',')
        to_int = [int(n) for n in intcodes]
        intcodes = to_int[:]
    intcodes[1] = 12
    intcodes[2] = 2

    return intcodes


    def arSlice(intcodes):

    opcode = intcodes[0::4]        
    first_input = intcodes[1::4]   
    second_input = intcodes[2::4]  
    outputs = intcodes[3::4]
    result = # put the 4 variables above into a single list or array?

    return intcodes, opcode, first_input, second_input, outputs


    def arCalc(intcodes, opcode, first_input, second_input, outputs):


    add_ = 1
    mul_ = 2
    index = 0

    while True:
        for o in opcode:
            if o == add_:
                intcodes[outputs[index]] = (intcodes[first_input[index]] + intcodes[second_input[index]])
                index += 1
            elif o == mul_:
                intcodes[outputs[index]] = (intcodes[first_input[index]] * intcodes[second_input[index]])
                index += 1
            elif o == 99:
                break
        break
    print(intcodes)

    def main():

    myFile = getFile("day2.txt")

    mySlice = arSlice(myFile)

    arCalc(myFile, mySlice)


    if __name__=="__main__":
          main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return multiple values from a function, it gets returned as a tuple:

```
def x():
    return "A", "cat", 5

y = x()
```

`y` now has the value `("A", "cat", 5)`. You can access each of these with `y[0]`, `y[1]`, and `y[2]`. Alternatively, you can assign them to separate variables when you call the function:

```
a, b, c = x()
```

Now `a` has the value `"A"`, `b` is `"cat"`, and `c` is `5`.

You can also expand a tuple as arguments when you pass it to a function, so assuming the variable `y` still exists as above:

```
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    pass
```

If you called `myfunc(y)` then in the function `a` would be the tuple `("A", "cat", 5)` and `b` and `c` would not get any values, resulting in an error. However if you called `myfunc(*y)` then y is expanded and `a` would get `"A"`, `b` would get `"cat"`, and `c` would get `5`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the values into a list,

```
result = [intcodes[0::4], ntcodes[1::4] , intcodes[2::4] , intcodes[3::4]]
```

Simply returning a value doesn't make it accessible from other scopes. However, you can store that value and pass it onto other methods. This is why you can access `intcodes` in the `arSlice` method.

```
def printValue(_value):
    print(_value)

def getValue():
    return 4

value = getValue()
printValue(value)
```

Comment: Aren't I storing opcode, first_input, second_input, and outputs? I fail to see the difference with how I stored intcodes in getFile() and the 4 variables in arSlice().